# При рекурсивном вызове функция выполняется дважды

Tags: javascript

Извиняюсь, что так мало контекста, приложение разбито на модули, поэтому уместить всё здесь не так просто.

Почему при клике на btnTrue/btnFalse функция game() проигрывается 2 раза, вместо одного?

Рабочее демо: https://beast1.github.io/demos/ph/ 
Полный код: https://github.com/beast1/287231-pixel-hunter/tree/m4t1

Рис.1 - game - принимает на вход параметры уровня и отрисовывает его
Рис.2 - levels(1) - массив объектов с уровнями
Рис.3 - getElement(2) - превращает строчный html в ноду
Рис.4 - updateWindow(3) - подставляет ноду в нужное место на экране

[image: game - принимает на вход параметры уровня и отрисовывает его]

[image: 1. levels - массив объектов с уровнями]

[image: 2. getElement - превращает строчный html в ноду]

[image: 3. updateWindow - подставляет ноду в нужное место на экране]

Answer (score 0):

Как оказалось дело было в том что для btnTrue/btnFalse использовалась вот такая разметка(рис.1), которая в комбинации с .addEventListener(`click`) давала двойное выполнение события при одном клике. Замена на .addEventListener(`mousedown`) решила проблему.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]